# unable to find reason for Segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I am writing the following code to process strings on the basis of their length but am getting the segmentation fault, googled about it and found that its related to pointers but am unable to figure out the reason for the same.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   char input[500];
   strcpy(input, "quick brown fox jumps on lazy dog");
   const char s[2] = " ";
   unsigned int num = 7;
   unsigned int lent;
   cin >> num;
   char *token;
   token = strtok(input, s);
   while( token != NULL ) 
   {
        lent= strlen(token);
        if(lent <= num)
            printf( " %s", token );
        token = strtok(NULL, s);
        if(strlen(token) <= (num-lent))
            printf("%s",token );
        printf("\n");
   }

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: This is the right time for you to learn `gdb`.

Comment: I am unable to get your point

Comment: You aren't checking if `strtok` in the loop returns `NULL`. Side note: your code is almost entirely C, there's nothing wrong with C but you might want to read a good C++ book published in the last 5 years if you want to write C++.

Comment: The point is that this kind of issue is so common that people made a tool to make this easier. It is called a debugger and will tell you exactly where the error is and let you look into variables to see why things failed. You should get used to one.

Comment: `<iostream.h>`?? What compiler are you using?

Comment: All that work, and in C++ all you need is [to do this](http://ideone.com/Rco7k7).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: 1989 Turbo C++ on a DOS emulator, and you already knew that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`token = strtok(NULL, s);`

You reach the end of your input string. And `token` becomes `NULL` at this line.  However you immediately follow that with `strlen(token)`.

Check `token` before any operation that may dereference it.